# Symfony2, How to load fixtures with --fixtures option?

Tags: symfony

I need an example for command below in Symfony2 :

```
php app/console doctrine:mongodb:fixtures:load --fixtures=/path/to/fixture
```

I don't know how to set the `--fixtures=/path/to/fixture`. I can load all together but I cannot do it for only one new fixture !

What format should /path/to/fixture be ?

Also I tried this `--fixtures=src/PMI/UserBundle/DataFixtures/ORM/FeatureFixtures` but I get this every time :

```
 [InvalidArgumentException]                             
  Could not find any fixtures to load in:                               
  - src/PMI/UserBundle/DataFixtures/ORM/FeatureFixtures
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I know this is old but other people have asked and these answers may not cover some of the other questions.

You only need to specify the folder, not the file.  In the above question, its not clear if FeatureFixtures is the php file or actually a folder.  It may be failing if that is only a php file and not a folder.  This is the correct way to load the fixtures assuming that FeatureFixtures is a php file with the fixtures:

```
doctrine:fixtures:load --fixtures=src/PMI/UserBundle/DataFixtures/ORM --append
```

Comment: If I understand well, the only way to load one fixture class is to put it in a dedicated directory

Comment: The --fixtures options does not exist any more since 3.x version. For now it is no more possible to specify the fixture to load. See https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineFixturesBundle/issues/219#issuecomment-352337579

Comment: As of DoctrineFixturesBundle v3.1.0 this is only possible with fixture GROUPS. See: https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-fixturesbundle-group-your-fixtures

Answer (score 4):

You can define a fixture with the real path.

```
php app/console doctrine:fixtures:load --fixtures=src/MyBundle/DataFixtures/ORM/LoadMyFixturesData.php
```

Comment: This will purge all the database and then load your specific fixture

Comment: Add `--append` to end of the line, in order to avoid purging the whole database and loading only this specific data fixture.

Answer (score 2):

It's not require but if you want to manually specify the directory where the fixtures classes should be loaded you can use this :

for example if I execute a command in directory symfony

```
--fixtures=/src/yourBundle/fixture
```

Comment: Should the path be absolute ?

Comment: you must choose a valid directory ,You can use an absolute or relative path

Comment: This command loads all the fixture files in the given absolute path. Is there any way to load only specific fixture file?

Comment: If you are going to use this command you are in the project directory and add the `./` (not absolute path to root with `/`) - like: `--fixtures=./src/yourBundle/DataFixtures/ORM`

Also if you do not want to blow out all of your data you should add `--append` at the end

Answer (score 0):

Starting with DoctrineFixturesBundle version 3.1 you need to use `doctrine:fixtures:load --group=FeatureFixtures`.

Answer (score -1):

For symfony +3 you can use this command:

`php bin/console doctrine:fixtures:load --group=YourFixtures --append`.

Or short version:

`php bin/console d:f:l --group=YourFixtures --append`.

---

where option:

- `--group` Target fixture. If you do not use the option, then load all your fixtures;
- `--append` Without this option the load fixture command will remove all data from your database. Use this option to add new data without removing old data.