# Fixtures + Migrations Doctrine, Symfony

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, fixtures

I want to create fixture, that generate 10 records in my table (test0-test9), then create migration, wherein I need to rename records, that was created by fixture to (category0-category9). 
I have created this fixture:

```
class AppFixtures extends Fixture
{
    public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
       {
        for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++)
        {
            $product = new Category();
            $product->setName('test '.$i);
            $id = mt_rand(89,140);
            $parent = $manager->getRepository(Category::class)->find($id);
            $product->setParent($parent);
            $manager->persist($product);
        }

        $manager->flush();
    }
}
```

But how I can rename this records in doctrine using migration? Any idea? 
* I think, I need to create sql queries directly in my migration class...or not

**UPDATE**

I try to do this, but I think it is bad solution...

```
public function postUp(Schema $schema)
    {
        $this->abortIf($this->connection->getDatabasePlatform()->getName() !== 'mysql', 'Migration can only be executed safely on \'mysql\'.');

        for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++)
        {
            $category = 'category '.$i;
            $test = 'test'.$i;
            $this->addSql('UPDATE category SET NAME = '.$category.' WHERE NAME = '.$test );
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can drop your table and run this particular fixture again check this 
`https://stackoverflow.com/a/21919497/2913267`

Comment: @l.g.karolos i don t need to load fixtures particular, I need to change values, using migrations

Answer (score 0):

You can inject the entity manager inside your migration.
Then you can find the object you want to change and change it.
I hope this answers your question

Example:

```
public function postUp(Schema $schema)
    {
        $em = $this->container->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');
        $products = $em->getRepository(Product::class)
               ->getProductsCustomQuery();

    foreach($product as $products){
        $product->setName(Whatever);                                                                       
    }
    $em->flush(); 
    }
```

Check this [link](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineMigrationsBundle/index.html#container-aware-migrations)

Comment: I don t understand what I need to do with that `->getProductsCustomQuery();` how can I search many values by name? I need to find test0 - test9 names and then update them. How can I do that with only one query?

Comment: You can replace that function with one that will find your products with name  `$test = 'test'.$i;`